# Axios unable get data from API in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, api, axios, nativescript

I have created a local API with Laravel. I have tried use Postman to run this API which is return me data, but when i using Axios in NativesScript Javascript file, it doesn't return the data nor error message.

I have tried use Async and Await in the function but still return nothing.

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default class Service {
  async testing(){
    await axios.get('https://app.app/api/testing')
        .then(res => {
           console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
           console.log(error);
        });
  }
}
```

I expect the output is 1, but it come out with "", and i found out that it never go to the API (I have put debug point, it no trigger.), but the Postman work just fine (same url), it trigger the debug point and it does return me value 1.

Thank you.

Comment: you can't use `await` and `then`, you can only use one of them. `axios.get(...).then().catch()` or `await axios.get(...)`

Comment: Thank you sir, but use any one them giving me out same result, it never active the API.

Comment: how do you call your function?

Comment: I call this function from method of Vue,   this.$service.testing()

Answer (score 0):

async/await should be wrapped inside try/catch block.

```
try {
    const result = await axios.get('https://app.app/api/testing');
    console.log(result)
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but it still remain the same, never active the API.